# Drawing border using R in shapefile based on dummy variable?

Tags: shapefile, r, borders

For an analysis in `R` I want to create a "new" border from a shapefile. The Shapefile comes with a dummy variable (zone_dummy) indicating the regions laying east and west from the border (see example below). Now I wanted to create a geomatric path along the border of the green and red municipalities:

[image]

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fzrveg1dzaklnxe/vz250.zip?dl=0) is my shapefile and below an example code:

```
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))

library(maptools)
library(RColorBrewer)

area <- readShapePoly("VZ250_GEM.shp")

kreise.data<-data.frame(area@data)

zone<-data.frame(c("Weiden i.d. OPf.", "Bad Kissingen", "Schweinfurt", "    Mellrichstadt", "Brückenau", "Rhön-Grabfeld",
               "Hofheim", "Ebern",  "Haßberge", "Coburg", "Hof", "Selb", "Kulmbach",
               "Marktredwitz", "Bayreuth", "Bamberg","Staffelstein", "Lichtenfels", "Kronach",
               "Stadtsteinach", "Naila", "Münchberg", "Rehau", "Wunsiedel", "Weiden",
               "Tirschenreuth", "Kemnath", "Neustadt a.d. Waldnaab", "Bad Neustadt a.d. Saale", "Neustadt b. Coburg", "Vohenstrauß", "Nabburg", 
               "Overviechtach", "Waldmünchen", "Cham", "Roding",
               "Deggendorf", "Passau", "Kötzling" ,"Viechtach", "Regen", "Bogen", "Grafenau",
               "Wolfstein", "Wegscheid", "Wunsiedel i. Fichtelgebirge", "Schwandorf", "Freyung-Grafenau"
               ))
#create dummy to mark municipalities in zone
colnames(zone)<-c("GEN_K")
zone$zone_dummy<-1
#merge with original data
kreise.data.zone<-merge(kreise.data, zone, by="GEN_K", all=T)
## Replace NA's with 0
kreise.data.zone[is.na(kreise.data.zone)] <- 0
##Merge assembled Shape-file Data Frame to Original Shapefile 
area.zone<-merge(area, kreise.data.zone)
#we only care about bavaria:
bayern<-subset(area.zone, area.zone@data$NUTS1_CODE=="DE2")
#plot a map of bavaria with zone: 
my.palette <- brewer.pal(n = 3, name = "Set1")
spplot(bayern, "zone_dummy", cuts = 1 , col.regions = my.palette, col="white", colorkey=FALSE)
```

My question is now: 
How can I create a border along the zone (=sharp border marking the path along the red and green municipalities)?

The idea is to (1) create this border in the shapefile (2) estimate the distance of each municipality in Bavaria to this border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the intersection of both geometries (e.g. `sf::st_intersection`), here is some R code using the `sf` package:

```
library("dplyr")
library("sf")

zone <- c("Weiden i.d. OPf.", "Bad Kissingen", "Schweinfurt", 
          "Mellrichstadt", "Brückenau", "Rhön-Grabfeld", "Hofheim", "Ebern",
          "Haßberge", "Coburg", "Hof", "Selb", "Kulmbach", "Marktredwitz",
          "Bayreuth", "Bamberg","Staffelstein", "Lichtenfels", "Kronach",
          "Stadtsteinach", "Naila", "Münchberg", "Rehau", "Wunsiedel",
          "Weiden", "Tirschenreuth", "Kemnath", "Neustadt a.d. Waldnaab",
          "Bad Neustadt a.d. Saale", "Neustadt b. Coburg", "Vohenstrauß",
          "Nabburg", "Overviechtach", "Waldmünchen", "Cham", "Roding",
          "Deggendorf", "Passau", "Kötzling" ,"Viechtach", "Regen", "Bogen",
          "Grafenau", "Wolfstein", "Wegscheid", "Wunsiedel i. Fichtelgebirge",
          "Schwandorf", "Freyung-Grafenau")

shp <- st_read("VZ250_GEM.shp") %>%
       filter(NUTS1_CODE=="DE2") %>%
       mutate(zone=factor(if_else(GEN_K %in% zone, 1, 0)))

border <- st_intersection(st_geometry(filter(shp, zone==1)),
                          st_geometry(filter(shp, zone==0)))

library("ggplot2")
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=shp, aes(fill=zone)) +
  geom_sf(data=border, colour="white", size=2)
```

[image: ggplot]